# MVC - HttpPost issue with Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 `HttpPost`. One is called by Json. And another is called when user submits the page.

When User clicks Delete button on page, i call `DeletePhone` method which deletes the records but problem is it also calls the another `[HttpPost]`(in below code 1st one).

How to stop calling another `[HttpPost]`?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Phones(Phones model)
        {
            ....
        }

[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeletePhone(int documentid)
        {
            string phoneName = Session["PhoneName"].ToString();
            bool result = settings.deletePhone(schemaName);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: make sure that your delete button is not input type submit..

Comment: plz post code where you are calling DeletePhone jsonresult..

Comment: Just changing `button` type to `button` done the thing. Grt..!

Comment: @Anup...Glad that i saved your time...hahaha....thankzz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are taking your delete button as input type submit that is why it is

submitting the form..Just take it as input type button..